# Forzar formato fecha en columna de gatagridview

Tags: visual-studio

hola quisiera pedirles de su ayuda
tengo un datagridview en el cual una columna es para ingreso de fechas lo que necesito es que al momento de ingresar las fechas se respete el formato dd/MM/yyyy    ya logre insertar una columna de datetimepicker pero me resulta muy complicado para el usuario entonces prefiero solo forzar este formato de fecha ala hora de escribir en la celda.
si me pudieran apoyar les estaré agradecido.

desarrollo> windows forms C#
aca esta el codigo que inserta el datetimepicker en la columna fecha.             pero no tengo idea de como forzar el formato fecha en tiempo de escritura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). lee [cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Debe agregar el código que está usando y la descripción de los errores que tenga. Sin mas información, es difícil que la comunidad entienda su pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la observación ise lo posible por corregirlo agradeseria mucho tu ayuda

Comment: Jaime. te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código "y no una captura de pantalla del código".